# How do I use an Apple Wireless Keyboard in the BIOS on a PC?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

Since I have seen no solutions to this, it seems like it's not possible?

Is this possible and if so, how do I need to set it up?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.  Apple wireless keyboards use BlueTooth for connectivity.  BlueTooth drivers are not loaded in Windows until Windows is loaded.

This is not the case for "regular" wireless keyboards though, they transmit directly to the USB wireless receiver.  As far as the computer is concerned, it appears to be a regular USB keyboard.

*Some* BlueTooth devices can act in a BlueTooth/"regular" wireless and can work before the driver is loaded, but if yours does not work, more than likely it is not a supported option.